# ¿Cómo asignar valor null a un DateTime en C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datetime, date, null

El problema que tengo es que estoy trayendome unos datos de una base. Entre estos datos están id, descripción y fecha (esta es un DateTime), entre otros.
El problema es que en la base de datos, el campo fecha tiene valor `null` y cuando creo el objeto con el cuál me traigo los datos, me da error que no se puede asignar `null` al campo del objeto.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnStr))
{
    Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    string queryDB = "SELECT * FROM secEmpresa WHERE idEmpresa=@idEmpresa";
    parameters.Add("@idEmpresa", idEmpresa);

    DataTable dtDB = DefineBD.dba_DataTable_ParamHash(queryDB, parameters);

    foreach (DataRow u in dtDB.Rows)
    {
        empresa.idEmpresa = u.Field<int>("idEmpresa");
        empresa.Nombre = u.Field<string>("Nombre");
        empresa.fecha = u.Field<DateTime>("fecha"); //Acá me da el error.
    }
}
```

Mi duda es: ¿Cómo puedo hacer para asignarle el valor sin importar que sea `null` o no?

Comment: ¿Probaste definiendo miembro 'fecha' de tu instancia 'empresa' como 'DateTime?' (tipo nullable)? En teoría la extensión Field soporta tipos nullables.

Comment: Si, el objeto (o instancia) `empresa` es una clase que contiene todos los campos de la tabla, entre ellos la fecha: `public DateTime fecha { get; set; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes probar con este cambio...

```
public class Empresa 
{
    public int idEmpresa {get; set;} 
    public string Nombre {get; set;}
    public DateTime? fecha {get; set;} //Nótese el ? que define un tipo Nullable.
}
```

Y tu código se vería así:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnStr))
{
    Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    string queryDB = "SELECT * FROM secEmpresa WHERE idEmpresa=@idEmpresa";
    parameters.Add("@idEmpresa", idEmpresa);

    DataTable dtDB = DefineBD.dba_DataTable_ParamHash(queryDB, parameters);

    foreach (DataRow u in dtDB.Rows)
    {
        empresa.idEmpresa = u.Field<int>("idEmpresa");
        empresa.Nombre = u.Field<string>("Nombre");
        empresa.fecha = u.Field<DateTime?>("fecha"); //Aquí está el soporte para Nulls.
    }
}
```

En teoría, así deberia funcionar.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda... lo probé y me funcionó perfecto!

Answer (score 3):

No se porque usas un `DataTable` para crear una entidad en lugar de un `SqlDataReader` que es mas optimo para iterar los registros

Pero bueno, bsicamente deberias validarlo

```
foreach (DataRow u in dtDB.Rows)
{
    empresa.idEmpresa = u.Field<int>("idEmpresa");
    empresa.Nombre = u.Field<string>("Nombre");

    empresa.fecha = u["fecha"] == DBNull.Value ? (DateTime?)null : u.Field<DateTime>("fecha");
}
```

por supuesto la propiedad `fecha` debes definirla del tipo `DateTime?` para que permita nulos

Comment: te sobro un "." en la ultima linea

Comment: si es verdad, ya edite el codigo para quitarlo

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero me pareció mas sencilla la opción de Javier y por eso la marqué como la respuesta correcta... y estoy usando un `DataTable` porque hace relativamente poco que programo en C# y hay muchísimas cosas de este lenguaje que se que puedo optimizar pero aún no sé como jajaja

Comment: Aplicar el `Field<DateTime?>` te valida si el campo es nulable ? imagine que no por eso puse la validacion explicita, pero bueno si funciono estara correcto